# WXPython, passing SetLabel() back to wx

Tags: python, attributes, wxpython

Python 3.8.6,
WXPython,
Experience - Noobster

Making a Gui that will play a video from a list after an event, like a button press. There is a test button and an "Add Video" button. When added a video I have it so it goes into 0 of a list. Then change the text/label to show the file that is loaded.
Below is an extract of the code that I am currently stuck with.

'''

```
class LeftPanel (wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, frame_object):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)

        self.frame_object = frame_object

        idleText = "Idle Animation"
        catIdleText = "None"

        idleLabel = wx.StaticText (self, 0, label = idleText + " - " + ntpath.basename(catIdleText), pos = (5, 5))
        testBtn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Test", pos = (5, 20))
        addBtn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add Video", pos = (85, 20))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.buttonPressed1, testBtn1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addVid1, addBtn1)


    def addVid1(self, event,):
       with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.mp4)|*.mp4", style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:
           if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
               return

           filePathList[0] = fileDialog.GetPath()
           catIdleText = filePathList[0]
           idleLabel.SetLabel("Idle Animation" + " - " + ntpath.basename(catIdleText)) **<--- where error occurs**
```

'''

Currently when the file is selected from the FileDialog the new updated text does not change. The error output comes out as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "frame1.py", line 179, in addVid1
       idleLabel.SetLabel("Idle Animation" + " - " + ntpath.basename(catIdleText))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'SetLabel'
```

I have also tried LeftPanel.catIdleText

I thought it would be quite a simple thing to pass the new update back up the initial catIdleText, however this is stumping me.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text(not screenshot). There are other useful informatio.

Comment: it seems you assign some text directly to variable `idleLabel = "text"` and now you don't have access to `Label` but to normal string.

Comment: if you wnat ot use `widgets` and other variable in different methods then you should use `self.` - ie, `self.idleLabel`, `self.catIdleText`

Comment: As @furas points out, you are in fact defining 2 different `local` variables, once in `def __init__` and another in `def addVid1`. You get around this issue by declaring them once, as `instance` variables i.e. `self.variable_name`.

Comment: @furas, apologies, I have edited the output error message to show full output from Traceback. Will do that now in the future.

Comment: Looks like @furas is the winner with your "if you wnat ot use widgets" post. That is the answer for this one. Can you post it as an answer to be voted on. It now passes the change to the label back and now shows the filename selected. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error can means you assigned some text directly to variable `idleLabel = "text"` and now you don't have access to `Label` but to normal `string`. But I don't see where in method `addVid1` you could do this.

But if you want to use `widgets` (and other variables) in different methods then you should use `self.` - ie, `self.idleLabel`, `self.catIdleText`.

```
def __init__(self, parent, frame_object):
    
    # ... code ....

    self.idleLabel = wx.StaticText(self, 0, label=idleText + " - " + ntpath.basename(catIdleText), pos=(5, 5))
   

def addVid1(self, event,):

    # .... code ...

       self.idleLabel.SetLabel("Idle Animation" + " - " + ntpath.basename(catIdleText))
```

Maybe this way you don't assing `text` to `self.idleLabel`